# the norm of a vector

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed non-zero column vector, $\|X\|=1$, and $H(t)$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which depends on $t$. The minimum eigenvalue of $H(t)$ may approach to zero for different $t$. Then, can we find a constant $C$ ($C$ may depend on $X$) such that
$$\left\|\frac{X^TH(t)}{X^TH(t)X}\right\|\leq C\|H(t)\|?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for example if $H = I$ the identity matrix you are requiring that
$ \frac{||x||}{||x||^2}<C ||I||= C $ or equivalently $$||x||^{-1}<C$$  for some $C>0$ which is impossible since $||x||\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0$.

More in general, since $H$ is  symmetric you can diagonalize and repeat the reasoning  on an eigenspace to get the contradiction.

**After the edit**
Consider the matrix $A_n = \frac{1}n\in M_{1\times1}(\mathbb{R})$ then for such $C>0$ you would have 
$$\frac{||A_n x||}{\langle x ,A_n x\rangle ||A_n||}< C$$, but for $x=1$ you have 
$$\frac{||A_n x||}{\langle x ,A_n x\rangle ||A_n||} = n\to +\infty$$

**Answering the comments**
$ \frac{||X||^2 H(t)}{|\langle X,H(t) X \rangle|}$ cannot be bounded for example consider the diagonal  2x2 matrices $H_n = diag(1, n)$. In this case for $X= e_1$ you have that 
$$ || \frac{||X||^2 H_n}{|\langle X,H_n X \rangle}|| = ||\frac{ H_n}{1}||\to \infty$$

Comment: How about $X$ fixed? Kindly remind that the right hand side of the inequality is the norm of $H$ instead of that of $X$.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice it, but the argument is still valid.

Comment: How about $\|X\|=1$? Let's fix  $X$.

Comment: I change the problem again to make it more clear.

Comment: Can I improve the answer in some way? Otherwise, why not accepting it?

Comment: Is it possible to bound $\frac{XX^TH(t)}{\|X^TH(t)X\|}$?

Comment: it is not clear what is the numerator, you mean the dot product  $\langle X , H(t)X\rangle$ or  $\langle X,X\rangle ||H(t)||$ or what?

Comment: $\langle X, H(t)X\rangle$

Comment: In this case it is bounded by the constant $1$ since the denominator is $||\langle X, H(t) X \rangle||$.

Comment: Could u give a proof?

Comment: $\frac {\langle X, H(t) X\rangle}{|\langle X, H(t) X\rangle|} \leq \frac {|\langle X, H(t) X\rangle|}{|\langle X, H(t) X\rangle|} \leq 1$

Comment: oh.. Sorry, I gave a wrong explanation. The numerator is $XX^TH(t)$. $XX^T$ is the product of a column vector and a row vector. It's a rank one matrix.